# How can I iterate through the pages of a wxNotebook?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

```
void Mainframe::OnClearNotebook( wxCommandEvent& e )
{
    int end = m_notebook->GetPageCount();
    for ( int i = 0; i < end; i++ )
    {
        if ( m_notebook->GetPageText( i ) != "Server Log" )
        {
            m_notebook->DeletePage(i);
        }
    }
}
```

This code crashes in this form with the message "m_notebook->GetPageText() index out of range";

**How do I correctly iterate through all pages?**

edit, the solution:

```
void Mainframe::OnClearNotebook( wxCommandEvent& e )
{   
    while ( m_notebook->GetPageCount() > 1 )
    {
        int end = m_notebook->GetPageCount() - 1;
        if ( m_notebook->GetPageText( end ) != "Server Log" )
        {
            m_notebook->DeletePage(end);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GetPageCount() will be changed if you are deleting pragmatically so end will hold earlier versions value

For Eg.

You have 100 in m_notebook->GetPageCount()

So end = 100

After iterating 10 items you are removing 5 items so now list will have 95 items but you are iterating upto 100 - This might be problem

Comment: That makes sense and yes it fixed the problem. Thank you. Basically I changed it to a loop and I am now deleting backwards, retrieving the new count each loop. It is weird though that the page id's get changed when a page is removed. There should be more consistency to identify tabs.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete items from a non-linked list, you will want to iterate the list, and collect the indices of all the list items that you want to delete in another new list. Once you are done iterating and collecting the indices, call delete on your original list with every index that you collected.